# iPhone loader creation

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder

I have an iPhone app which, when it launches, loads in data from a remote database.

How would I go about displaying a loader on the screen from the point the app sends a request to the database to the point where the app has received the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a pretty good code snippet from iPhone Cookbook (Erica Sadun). What I like about it, is it adds a UIProgressView to an ActionSheet that animates from the button of the iPhone screen.

http://ipsw.info/trac/browser/iphone-3.0-cookbook/C10-Alerts/07-Progress%20View/main.m

Answer (score 0):

Use UIProgressView or UIActivityIndicatorView. Do you need help with a more specific aspect of this?